# How does Terraform knows which AWS account to apply the changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Coming from Terraform GCP to AWS, I am wondering how does Terraform knows which AWS account to apply the changes to? In GCP, you can assign a project id to the resource/provider so that i know exactly which project Terraform will apply the changes to.

For setting up Terraform for AWS, the plan is to use assume role. Is this the best practice to setup multiple accounts? (We only have 2 account, ideally i think it is better to have a separate `dev-ops` account )

1. Create a `terraform-role` in both dev and prod account.
2. Create a user `infra-user` in dev account.
3. Setup trust policy between `terraform-role` in dev/prod account and user `infra-user`
4. Use variable to toggle between dev/prod in the Terraform AWS assume role.

I am guessing when Terraform assumes the role, it also assumes to create the resources in that account?

Comment: You should not be able to go from dev to prod, ***EVER***. Instead set them up identically and either give terraform two profiles, two sets of credentials or ... but do not set up any trust between dev and prod. Why have a user in the first place? From where are you deploying?

Comment: thanks for the comments, yes we can definitely create 2 separate set of credentials, one for dev and one for prod. 
We have the devops server (gitlab runner) setup in the dev account, which will be used to execute the Terraform code.
Without a user, how am i supposed to authenticate with aws from terraform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AWS, the target account for operations is always implied by the principal (user or role) that's making the API call. If you use `sts:AssumeRole` (or similar) and then make API calls with the resulting dynamic credentials then you'll be making requests against the account that the target role belongs to, rather than as the account that your original principal (the one that assumed the role) belongs to.

AWS APIs don't typically take an account ID as part of the request, so there isn't any direct analog to associating each object with a project in GCP. This is more a design detail of AWS itself than of the `hashicorp/aws` provider for Terraform.

However, you can help ensure that you keep your account IDs in order by setting the `allowed_account_ids` argument in your `provider "aws"` block(s). If you set that then before making any other requests the AWS provider will call [`sts:GetCallerIdentity`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetCallerIdentity.html) and make sure that the `Account` indicated in the response matches one of those given in `allowed_account_ids`, returning an error if not.

Comment: Thanks Martin, that clarifies a lot !

Comment: Martin, if i were to setup terraform in a multiple account how does it know which s3 bucket to use?
say I have aws account `devops` where the terraform pipeline will be executed, which deploys to account `dev`, `uat` and `prod`. In the provider, I can switch the assume role based on the target environment. Will the state file be stored in the s3 bucket of the target account. 
How to configure it so that all the state file will be stored in the `devops` account s3 bucket?
Or by default, Terraform will use the account of the user for the backend as apposed to the role?

Comment: S3 is a little special compared to most AWS services in that the bucket namespace is global: although a particular bucket does belong to a particular AWS account, the name of that bucket is reserved across all accounts in all regions and so the bucket IAM policy decides whether a request from another account is allowed. If you want to use a separate bucket per account then they will each need to have a different name, and you'll need to configure those different names in Terraform. If you need more details about this then I suggest making a new Stack Overflow question to allow a fuller answer.